# .htaccess main domain to subfolder, but /subfolder is still reachable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a parked domain http://example2.com that is on the hosting platform http://example.com.

Problem is that if I go to http://example2.com/example2/fr, I don't get redirected to http://example2.com/fr and I've tried solutions but keep having a redirection loop.

In the public_html folder, there is a subfolder /example2 with the files for http://example2.com

```
> public_html
  - .htaccess
  - index.php
  > assets
  > css
  > js
  > example2
    - .htaccess
    - index.html
    > fr
      - index.html
    > en
      - index.html
```

Now, in the public_html folder, my redirect rule in my .htaccess file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Redirect the example2 to the subfolder /example2
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example2\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule !^example2/ /example2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

In the /example2 folder, my htaccess file redirects like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

  #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What happens if your remove the /subfolder/.htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/example2/.htaccess` should be like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]

# remove /example2/ from URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+example2(/\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm :)